# How to create a single dask array from multiple files?

Tags: python, arrays, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to create a single `dask array` from multiple files. I am using `dask.array.Array` class to do that. Consider the following code snippet where I am generating `100` random integer `array` of size `(3, 10, 10)` and saving each of them in a separate `npy` file. Then I am trying to create a single `dask array` to combine all these arrays into a single `dask array` of shape `(3, 100, 100)`.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from dask import array as da
from dask.base import tokenize

names = list()
for i in range(100):
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (3, 10, 10))
    fn = 'data/array_{}.npy'.format(i)
    np.save(fn, arr)
    names.append('Array-{}'.format(tokenize(fn)))

indices = list(product(range(10), range(10)))

dsk = {
    (name, 0, *index): (np.load, name)
    for name, index in zip(names, indices)
}
namex = 'Combined_Array'
dtype=int
shape = (3, 100, 100)
chunks = (3, 10, 10)
d = da.Array(dsk, namex, chunks, dtype, shape)
```

Unfortunately it throws an error in `normalize_chunks` method:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-008559464c9e> in <module>
----> 1 d = da.Array(dsk, namex, chunks, dtype, shape)

~/.conda/envs/Py3Dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in __new__(cls, dask, name, chunks, dtype, meta, shape)
   1026         else:
   1027             dt = None
-> 1028         self._chunks = normalize_chunks(chunks, shape, dtype=dt)
   1029         if self._chunks is None:
   1030             raise ValueError(CHUNKS_NONE_ERROR_MESSAGE)

~/.conda/envs/Py3Dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in normalize_chunks(chunks, shape, limit, dtype, previous_chunks)
   2481             )
   2482 
-> 2483     return tuple(tuple(int(x) if not math.isnan(x) else x for x in c) for c in chunks)
   2484 
   2485 

~/.conda/envs/Py3Dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/array/core.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2481             )
   2482 
-> 2483     return tuple(tuple(int(x) if not math.isnan(x) else x for x in c) for c in chunks)
   2484 
   2485 

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing the arguments as named arguments solved the problem as there are parameters which are not included in this example and order of those arguments changed. Also there are other bugs in the code. The correct code would be:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from dask import array as da

names = list()
for i in range(100):
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 9, (3, 10, 10))
    fn = 'data/array_{}.npy'.format(i)
    np.save(fn, arr)
    names.append(fn)

indices = list(product(range(10), range(10)))
namex = 'Combined_Array'
dsk = {
    (namex, 0, *index): (np.load, name)
    for name, index in zip(names, indices)
}

dtype=int
shape = (3, 100, 100)
chunks = (3, 10, 10)

d = da.Array(dask=dsk, name=namex, chunks=chunks, dtype=dtype, shape=shape)
```

See the related [github issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5906) for the detailed discussion.